# Is this the correct way to handle C multi-dimensional array navigation

Tags: c, pointers

My concern is that the way I calculate the end of td is correct.  Is this optimal?  Is there a better C idiom to do this type of thing?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char td[][4] = { {0,1,2,3}, {4,5,6,7}, {8,9,10,11}, 
                      {12,13,14,15}, {16,17,18,19}, {20,21,22,23}  };
    char* p = *td;  

    int rows = sizeof(td) / sizeof(td[0]);
    int cols = sizeof(td[0]) / sizeof(td[0][0]);

    char* end = p + (rows * cols);

    /* Print first element in each 'row' */
    while(p != end) {
        printf("first element: %u\n", p[0]);
        p += 4;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Correct way means? this is a way but not simple and chances of bugs are more. (so may be correct but not preferable)

Comment: Is this the reason behind all your other posts? Just reference your data by td[0][0], td[1][0], etc. There's no problem with doing that. It takes no longer to calculate td[1] than it does it increment p by 4.

Comment: That is certainly _a_ way, but one of the more obtuse. A double `for` loop over the indices would be clearer, more concise, and less error prone.

Comment: Are you focusing on performance? Because there are many ways to do it.

Comment: Note if you concern for speed/efficient purpose where pointer `p[]` and `td[][]` both are equally good, but `td[][]` quite a simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would typically use a for loop in C.

```
int main() {
    char td[][4] = { {0,1,2,3}, {4,5,6,7}, {8,9,10,11}, 
                      {12,13,14,15}, {16,17,18,19}, {20,21,22,23}  };

    int rows = sizeof(td) / sizeof(td[0]);
    int cols = sizeof(td[0]) / sizeof(td[0][0]);

    /* Print first element in each 'row' */
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        printf("first element: %u\n", td[row][0]);

    return 0;
}
```

However, the code you have written does work.

Comment: There is no need for `p += 4` anymore.

Comment: I see what you mean re: clarity.  With mbratch's COLS define below yes that is probably better looking.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define COLS 4
int main() {
    char td[][COLS] = { {0,1,2,3}, {4,5,6,7}, {8,9,10,11}, 
                      {12,13,14,15}, {16,17,18,19}, {20,21,22,23}  };

    int rows = sizeof(td) / sizeof(td[0]);

    /* print the matrix */
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            printf("first element: %u\n", td[row][col]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For the first column of each row:

```
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        printf("first element: %u\n", td[row][0]);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you have to loop through the columns for printing the first element in each row? `printf("first element: %u\n", td[row][0]);` will suffice.

Comment: @VarunLakkur sorry I was illustrating printing every column. I will add that case.